# Transfer money in my US account to brother's Non Resident External (NRE) Account in India

Tags: united-states, india, international, f1-student-visa

I'm a student in US on F1. I want to send 2k$ in my US account to my brother's State Bank of India NRE(Non Resident External) in India. There is NO rush in sending this money.. as in the money need not reach immediately. How do I send this amount without loosing much on conversion, etc. This is a special case because of the NRE account type. Also, I can increase the transfer amount to 5.5k to save on conversion money.
I want to know how should I send this money: online/DD/check... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you can send a Check by mail, you brother deposits into Bank account. It costs very little, the time required would be around 1-2 months.

You can do International Wire [Via SWIFT] it would reach in few days, fees are high.

You can use specialized remittance services like Money2india, remit2india, or western union etc. The fees are low and generally funds reach in a week.

Comment: Instead of mail, could I deposit the check by myself in the SBI bank branch close to me in San Jose, California, USA (http://www.sbical.com/) ?

Comment: @ironhyde You can check if they offer you the services of taking a check to credit to Indian Bank Account. They may suggest a internal wire transfer that should be easy

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Transferwise. I find them good for currency conversions and paying people in India from a US bank account.